# Searching a String array to find portions of elements

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I have a String array that has individuals names in it (example):

```
["John Smith", "Ramon Ruiz", "Bill Bradford", "Suzy Smith", "Brad Johnson"]
```

I would like to write a method that prompts a user to input (in form of String) a name OR portion of a name, and then lists all names that contain the string entered by the user, (I can fix the case issue easily).

ex:

```
Name: rad  (meaning user enters "rad")

Output:
Bill Bradford
Brad Johnson
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this (one that also preserves white spaces)?  If there already is a good example of this, feel free to link me.  I was unable to find a good method in API.

Comment: _"I was unable to find a good method in API."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thank you.  This should do it.

Comment: If you want to ignore casing, you could call `.toUpper()` or `.toLower()` on both strings before making the check.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
for(String name : names) {
    if(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(name, stringToLookFor)) {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.indexOf()` it return -1 if it does not find a subString into a String.

```
for(String name : myArray)
{
    if (name.indexOf("rad") != -1) {
        // contains word
    }
}
```